# setFormulas missing ]

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am trying to write my first script. It is supposed to fill out a group of formulas with variables set by the user (not sure if variables is the right word).

I am getting a missing ] error on line 13 with this code, can anyone spot where it is missing from? All brackets seem to be paired just fine :S

```
function setFormula(formulas) {

  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();
  //Asks for Cell range data
var week = Browser.inputBox("Week:");
  var start = Browser.inputBox("Start:");
var end = Browser.inputBox("End:");  

 // The magic
 var formulas = [

   ["=SUM('Week " + week + "'!E" + start + ":E" + end +")"],
   ["=COUNTIF('Week " + week + "'!E" + start + ":E" + end +";""Test/Media"")"],
   ["=COUNTIF('Week " + week + "'!E" + start + ":E" + end +";""Test/Hardware"")"]


 ];
//Highlighted cell range will get the magic
 var range = sheet.getActiveRange();
 range.setFormulas(formulas);
}
```

Thanks for any help or suggestions :)

Answer (score 0):

```
+";""..."
```

This is invalid syntax.

Javascript string literals use backslash as an escape character, so you should write

```
+";\"..."
```

Comment: If I add another \ after the words Hardware and Media the code will compile, but nothing happens on my sheet.

Answer (score 0):

You can throw off the parenthesizer (c) with misplaced quotes, which is the case here.

```
["=COUNTIF('Week " + week + "'!E" + start + ":E" + end +";""Test/Media"")"],
                                                          ^^          ^^

    ... should be ...

["=COUNTIF('Week " + week + "'!E" + start + ":E" + end +";'Test/Media')"],
```

... and repeat on the next line.

You've got two options in javascript when you need to have quotes within a string.

1. Use single quotes inside a string delimited by double quotes (or vice-versa), as you were doing already. (You just missed a few.)
2. Escape single quotes with <kbd>\</kbd>, as in:

   ```
   ';\'Test/Media\')'
   ```